# Is there any way to know how much disk space a indexed field take in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm indexing a document with mapped fields defined, the disk size ended up too much and I want to inspect how much disk space each indexed fields take?

Is there any way to do it? Index stats here seems only display the overall for all fields (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html)

- Index fields mapping

```json
{
    '_source': {
        'enabled': False,
    },
    'properties': {
        'ip': {
            'type': 'ip',
        },
        'timestamp': {
            'type': 'date',
        },
        'data': {
            'type': 'text',
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Update index stats

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/allocation?v"
shards disk.indices disk.used disk.avail disk.total disk.percent host       ip         node
     3        6.3mb    28.3gb       30gb     58.4gb           48 172.17.0.3 172.17.0.3 57dac878cf46
     2                                                                                 UNASSIGNED

curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v"
health status index                           uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   my-index                        vjdK1nkRRimxtdUvgKWNHA   1   1      10000            0      6.3mb          6.3mb
yellow open   .kibana                         kDM_5IpMQfacYN6F2_mxrQ   1   1          1            0        5kb            5kb
```

Comment: What kind of field type is that?

Comment: I think in my case is keyword, text fields as it might take up more space than others

Comment: Can you share your index mapping please?

Comment: Added, and yeah I just want to know how much disk space a field take, for example, field `data` above

Comment: Can you also update your question with the responses you get from the following commands: `GET _cat/indices?v` and `GET _cat/allocation?v` ?

Comment: Updated, note that I just index a small portion of data

Comment: Can you add the `?v` to the URL not `?pretty`

Comment: Ok, just updated

Comment: So your index is using 6.3 MB for 10000 documents (~630 bytes per doc) and you think it's too much? Can you explain what makes you think that? Also can you share how many bytes does a single document weigh when stored in a text file?

Comment: yeah, actually not, I just index a demo, the actual size around 19Mb/10000 docs (JSON file size ~100Mb), and I actually much more data. Anw, I found that `data` field consuming too much disk space, sometimes, it contains 10000 - 50000 characters

Comment: Always start from the need! What is the use case with the data field? What do you need to do with it? How do you want to search on it?

Comment: Yeah, I might need to refactor/truncate that field a bit

Comment: You haven't answered my question :-)

Comment: This field contains raw data the I collect, I might want to use search phrase on it so disable some options in the `text` field is not ideal, like norms, index_options

Comment: 10000 - 50000 characters in a single text field can indeed grow big. You need to understand exactly what you need to do with that field in order to optimize it. Feel free to share more details on your use case, show sample data, sample queries, etc

Comment: yeah ok, I think I need to recheck my case, anw my question about is there any way to know much disk space a field take, we can't, right?

Answer (score 1):

The value of a given field might not be stored only once in a single place, there are many different underlying data structures in Lucene.

You can find more information in this thread which answers the same question: https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Get-size-occupied-by-each-field-in-lucene-index-td4347856.html